# Is there an app to display partition identifers?

Tags: partitioning, command-line

I'd like to know if an app exists that list all partitions, their filesystem type, and their possible identifiers.

This could help users in configuring their bootloaders.

For example:

```
Identifier      Grub Identifier     Filesystem Type     Size
 /dev/sda1       (hd0,2)             ext4                37GB
 /dev/sda4       (hd0,5)             NTFS                20GB
```

Is there an app with functionality similar to this that anyone knows of?

Comment: is `sudo fdisk -l` what you are asking? It shows an `id` and it list `83` as `83 Linux native partition`

Comment: yeah, but i was thinking of something that would also list the (hdX,Y) stuff that grub needs.. It could be useful for users that aren't too familiar with the naming conventions

Comment: Try `sudo sfdisk -l` see if its what you want.

Comment: well, it's interesting, but from a new user's point of view i think it's even more confusing than `fdisk -l`, what with all the additional info..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [**di**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/di.1.html)

```
sudo apt-get install di
```

then

```
di -a
```

gives something close to your requirement

```
Filesystem         Mount               Size     Used    Avail %Used  fs Type              
/dev/sda8          /                  48.8G    14.0G    32.3G   34%  ext4                 
udev               /dev                1.9G     0.0G     1.9G    0%  devtmpfs             
devpts             /dev/pts            0.0M     0.0M     0.0M    0%  devpts               
gvfs-fuse-daemon   /home/user/.gvf     0.0M     0.0M     0.0M    0%  fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon
/dev/sda5          /media/01CC6E45   293.0G   284.9G     8.1G   97%  fuseblk              
/dev/sda6          /media/01CC6E45   390.6G   355.6G    35.0G   91%  fuseblk              
/dev/sda7          /media/01CC6E45    97.7G    94.2G     3.5G   96%  fuseblk              
/dev/sda2          /media/0E246764    97.6G    34.1G    63.5G   35%  fuseblk              
/dev/sdb1          /media/748d0c01    20.0G     5.8G    13.2G   34%  ext4                 
/dev/sdb5          /media/f452a714    18.6G     7.2G    10.5G   44%  ext4                 
/dev/sdb4          /media/New Volu   255.5G    68.1G   187.4G   27%  fuseblk              
proc               /proc               0.0M     0.0M     0.0M    0%  proc                 
binfmt_misc        /proc/sys/fs/bi     0.0M     0.0M     0.0M    0%  binfmt_misc          
tmpfs              /run              772.7M     0.8M   771.9M    0%  tmpfs                
none               /run/lock           0.0M     0.0M     0.0M    0%  tmpfs                
none               /run/shm            0.0M     0.0M     0.0M    0%  tmpfs                
sysfs              /sys                0.0M     0.0M     0.0M    0%  sysfs                
none               /sys/fs/fuse/co     0.0M     0.0M     0.0M    0%  fusectl              
none               /sys/kernel/deb     0.0M     0.0M     0.0M    0%  debugfs              
none               /sys/kernel/sec     0.0M     0.0M     0.0M    0%  securityfs
```

but without the Grub Identifier `( although the sda8 can be seen as (hd0,8) from Filesystem column)`  .And for entire disk information , all the available partitions needs to be mounted.

---

Another one is [disktype](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/disktype.1.html) but with more details including UUID

example  `sudo disktype /dev/sdx`

```
Partition 6: 390.6 GiB (419423445504 bytes, 819186417 sectors from 819186480+63)
    Type 0x07 (HPFS/NTFS)
    Windows NTLDR boot loader
    NTFS file system
      Volume size 390.6 GiB (419423444992 bytes, 819186416 sectors)
  Partition 7: 97.65 GiB (104855837184 bytes, 204796557 sectors from 1638372960+63)
    Type 0x07 (HPFS/NTFS)
    Windows NTLDR boot loader
    NTFS file system
      Volume size 97.65 GiB (104855836672 bytes, 204796556 sectors)
  Partition 8: 48.89 GiB (52500103168 bytes, 102539264 sectors from 1843169580+1748)
    Type 0x83 (Linux)
    Ext3 file system
      UUID 0F493AF5-3B1C-49A5-B33E-5E04F42CA0F1 (DCE, v4)
      Last mounted at "/"
      Volume size 48.89 GiB (52500103168 bytes, 12817408 blocks of 4 KiB)
  Partition 9: 3.725 GiB (3999268864 bytes, 7811072 sectors from 1945712475+165)
    Type 0x82 (Linux swap / Solaris)
    Linux swap, version 2, subversion 1, 4 KiB pages, little-endian
      Swap size 3.725 GiB (3999260672 bytes, 976382 pages of 4 KiB)
```

Comment: Good answer. Not exactly what I was looking for, but I'll accept it anyway! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to install anything, just:

```
ls /dev/disk/by-uuid -lah
```

gives you for example:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jun 27 10:56 7d4d0682-4f05-41d7-b3a3-871799e1014c -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jun 27 10:56 a22643b0-8de4-4feb-859a-1ba7eb84bf2f -> ../../sda5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use gparted or lparted.

Answer (score 1):

Another choice, installed by default on 12.04:

```
sudo lsblk -f
```

There are options to display fields, remove headers, etc.

```
sudo blkid
```

may also be useful, depending upon what you find easier to parse.

I don't think it will be easy to find a standard utility to convert to the grub nomenclature. The shell program /usr/lib/grub-legacy/update-grub has some shell script functions that do the conversion.